# Azure Mobile App authentication only with Azure AD but Windows Account can also login?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services, azure-active-directory

Why after setup my Mobile App authentication **only with Azure AD**, the authentication popup window can allow not only my company account, but also allow public Windows Account like @outlook.com to be authenticated?

I follow [this official procedures](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication/) and I did check that Microsoft Account authentication is "Not Configured."

It's very weird.

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because the @outlook.com account you are testing with is also a guest member of your Azure AD tenant. Try using a new @outlook.com account or one owned by a friend who has no connections to your organization to verify.

Comment: Thanks. It's like what you said after verification. 
So, what if the @outlook.com account is only for Azure management and we don't want that non-company account to login in my Apps, is that possible?

Comment: To ensure that only organizational employees can access your app, you would need to add some logic to your app code. If this is an ASP.NET 4.x web app, you can use ClaimsPrincipal.Current to find the set of claims. From there you can see various properties of the authenticated user and use those to make additional AuthZ decisions.  For example, you could check the email address to see whether it is part of your organization's domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can config multi authentication providers in your Azure App Services. And there are needed to configured manually. The post you provided guides you how to config AAD to your Azure App Service. To config Microsoft Account provider, you can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-microsoft-authentication/.

Additionally, you can set the default authentication provider as the image:
[image]

And as your requirement, you can manually choose the authentication provider in your client code, E.G. in cordova sample:

```
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient("<mobile_app_url>");
// use aad
client.login('aad').then(
...
)
// use microsoft account
client.login('microsoftaccount').then(
...
)
```

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks, Gary. But on the contrary, I don't want Windows Account to be authenticated in Azure AD authentication since the our app only allow company account.